# Is there a quick way to find all unique identifiers in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with over 100 columns, I would like to check all pairs to see which are unique identifiers.

Comment: Please provide a sample.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? Add some code into the post? The dataframe is quite big (new to stack overflow)

Comment: See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We can hardly know what you are talking about. i assume a pandas dataframe. I do no know pandas but this kind of issue is not pandas specific.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. Sorry if unclear - my first question. And yes this is a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drop_duplicates(subset)`, specifying the columns you would regard as possible identifiers in the `subset` argument.

Since you have so many columns it will probably be easiest to take all columns and subtract from them the ones you would disregard (such as value columns).

Answer (score -1):

You can use from collections import counter. [see doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)